# Maximum of $f(a_1,...,a_N)=E\left[\prod_{i=1}^N X_i\right]$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, optimization, reference-request, stochastic-processes

Suppose $X_t$ is a stochastic process such that

$$X_{i+1}=|a_i-a_{i-1}|+X_i+\epsilon_i$$

where $a_i\geq0$ and $\epsilon_i\sim N(0,1)$ and $i\in\{1,...,N\}$.

Define $$f(a_1,...,a_N)=E\left[\prod_{i=1}^N X_i\right]$$.

Are there any methods to find $a^*=\arg\!\max_{0\leq a_1,...,a_N\leq K} f(a_1,...,a_N)$ by simulating the paths of $X_i$?

Additional assumption $\sum_{i=1}^N a_i=c>0$

Comment: The max doesn't exist, in order words, $f$ can go to $+\infty$. For example, $N = 3$ take $a_2 = a_1 + L$ with $L \to +\infty$

Comment: @NN2 what if we search in a bounded region?